# Algebraic pyramid python challenge- more efficient way?

Tags: python

I'm doing a python challenge where you have to create an upside-down algebraic pyramid based on a list. Each level (going down) needs to be the sum of the numbers above it.

I created the code to do this for 4 layers.

The challenge part 2 was to do it for any length of list, so I added the len(list) code to accommodate. You can see my code below.

I just wondered if there was a more efficient way to do this for long lists, or would I just need to type out more code for the remaining layers.

Also, I wondered how the return statement is meant to fit into it (you're given the hint written in the code below to update the return statement).

```
 def drawPyramid(list):
  layer = ""
  layer2 = " "
  layer3 = "  "
  layer4 = "   "
  for i in range(len(list)):
    layer = layer + " " + str(list[i])
  for i in range(len(list)-1):
    layer2 = layer2 + " " + str(list[i]+list[i+1])
  for i in range(len(list)-2):
    layer3 = layer3 + " " + str(list[i]+(list[i+1]*2)+list[i+2])
  for i in range(len(list)-3):
    layer4 = layer4 + " " + str(list[i]+(list[i+1]*3)+(list[i+2]*3)+list[i+3])
  print(layer)
  print(layer2)                              
  print(layer3)
  print(layer4) 
  #Update this code to generate all 4 layers of the pyramid
  
  #Update this return statement to return the value of the single brick on the last layer of the pyramid
  return 0
  
  
#Main code starts here  
list = [30,12,10,22]
drawPyramid(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here this function will calculate your pyramid using list:

```
def calcul_pyramid(base):
    pyramid = [base]
    for i in range(len(base) - 1):
        actual_layer = []
        last_layer = pyramid[i]
        for j in range(len(last_layer) - 1):
            actual_layer.append(last_layer[j] + last_layer[j + 1])
        pyramid.append(actual_layer)
    return pyramid
```

This function will get your pyramid as string:

```
def print_pyramid(pyramid):
    lines = []
    for layer in pyramid:
        line = ""
        for brick in layer:
            line += str(brick)
            line += " "
        lines.append(line)
    pyramid_len = max([len(layer) for layer in lines])
    txt = ""
    for line in lines:
        diff = (pyramid_len - len(line)) / 2
        txt += " " * int(diff + 0.5)
        txt += line
        txt += " " * int(diff - 0.5)
        txt += "\n"
    print(txt)
```

Now you can enter every base you want, it will work

```
print_pyramid(calcul_pyramid([30,12,10,22])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What I don't understand though (amongst other things!) is:
len(last_layer)

Won't this always be 1, as pyramid[i] will always just be one number?

Comment: pyramid[i] is a layer and a layer has bricks, so len(last_layer) will count the number of brick of the last layer. (I call brick a number)

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to add up the values, then it's just a question of formatting:

```
def pyramid(A):
    indent = ""
    width  = len(str(sum(A)))
    while A:
        print(indent,*(f"{a:{width}}" for a in A))
        A = [a+b for a,b in zip(A,A[1:])]
        indent += " "*max(1,width-1)
```

output:

```
L = [30,12,10,22]
pyramid(L)

 30 12 10 22
  42 22 32
   64 54
    118


L = [30,12,10,22,23,43]
pyramid(L)

  30  12  10  22  23  43
    42  22  32  45  66
      64  54  77 111
       118 131 188
         249 319
           568
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Having looked at your solution, it's way too advanced for me to understand. I've tried. Like, I don't understand why you are getting the length of the sum of the list. In the first example list, the sum is 64- why is the length of 64 relevant?

The challenge was meant to be a relative beginner onen so I thought the solution would be simplish. I'm sure one day I can come back to it and understand.

Comment: `len(str(sum(A)))` is merely a naive way to get an idea of the size of the numbers in the pyramid in order to use a regular width and indentation for formatting purposes.   I could have computed the final number to get the exact size but that seemed a bit overkill.